# Laravel 5.4 themed layouts

Tags: layout, laravel-5, theming

I would like apply on a laravel 5.4 project some basic theme switching ability.

I made under config folder a site.php config file where I added the following

```
return [

    'theme' => realpath(base_path('my_theme/views'))

];
```

than in controller I call it like

```
Config::get('site.theme')
```

but when I try to pass to my controller I get `View not found` however the showed path is correct

How do I implement in case of laravel some basic theming functionality?

**I got it between**

config/views.php

```
'paths' => [
    //resource_path('views'),
    realpath(base_path('themes/my_theme/views'))
],
```

but still interested how would I apply a multi theme templating system in case of laravel

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the theme as a layout. See the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#defining-a-layout

This will allow you to build out a structured layout and then in your application you can switch which one you want to use between views. Typically all my views have an `@extends('layouts.app')` directive at the top. You could easily replace 'layouts.app' with whatever value you store in a config and a user chooses.